# How to back up Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: backup

Now that Remastersys is no longer available in the repos, what is the best to use for making a complete backup (hopefully available in Software Center) for Ubuntu 12.04 64bit?

I have been told Relinux is good, is there something else that will work better?

Comment: Have you looked at [Back In Time](http://backintime.le-web.org/)?

Comment: It is pretty much the same thing as deja dup, I need to make a complete backup including the Kernel just in case something goes horribly wrong when I try to install Windows 8 or 7.  I may need to restore the entire partition.

Answer (score 1):

Try Deja Dup.You can view screenshots here: http://www.howtogeek.com/108869/how-to-back-up-ubuntu-the-easy-way-with-dj-dup/

Comment: Okay, I tried it but it looks like I need to run it from a Live CD.  I told it to backup / and to ignore downloads, trash, media and windows.  It came back with several files that it could not backup including the kernel.